# chartjs: trying to rotate the y-Axis label

Tags: chart.js

I've tried things like `maxRotate` and `rotate`, placing them in `scaleLabel` and so on. I couldn't find anything in the docs, and the search results on google are not much of a help either.

```
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 0
        }
      },
      scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true
              },
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'MW',
              },
          }],
          xAxes: [
            {
              gridLines: {
              display: false ,
              color: "#FFFFFF"
            },
            ticks: {
              callback: function(tick, index, array) {
                return (index % 2) ? "" : tick;
              }
            }
          }]
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the Y-axis in Chart.js 2.0 with the tick property. There's a link here.

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks : {
    minRotation : 90
  }
}]
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/acmfk5p8/

There's a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622839/rotate-yaxis-main-title-chart-js) but it doesn't have an answer yet either.