# Rotate yAxis main title chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

is there way how to rotate main title (Čas [ms]) of yAxis please? I am using chart.js and this is code of chart.

Thank you

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: vlakna,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: cas,
        label: "Čas",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
    options : {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Čas [ms]'
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Vlákna'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

[Rotate title yAxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIpX1.png)

Comment: Potential duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306604/chartjs-trying-to-rotate-the-y-axis-label  Still with no answer however

Comment: I am so sorry I did not know that.