# Ability to rotate y axis title in chart.js

Tags: javascript, rotation, chart.js

I'm trying to rotate the title of the y axis 90 degrees clockwise in chart.js but I couldn't find any way to do this.

This question [chartjs: trying to rotate the y-Axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306604/chartjs-trying-to-rotate-the-y-axis-label) only rotates the ticks/labels not the y axis title itself.

The only related post I can find is this [Ability to rotate axis title](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8345) and the response was from Jan 26, 2021 saying there was no way to do this.

I have attached my javascript and html code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The y axis title I would like to rotate is highlighted in red and called: **Number of defects**. Ideally I'd like to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise.
[image]

```js
const labels = ['2021-06-07 00:00:00', '2021-06-08 00:00:00', '2021-06-09 00:00:00'];

        const data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Fixed defects',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                    data: ['2', '73', '34'],
                    barThickness: 5
                }, {
                    label: 'Open defects',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                    data: ['0', '5', '2'],
                    barThickness: 5
               
                }]
        };

        const config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: {
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        min: '2021-06-07 00:00:00',
                        max: '2021-09-10 00:00:00',
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'week'
                        },
                        stacked: true,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Dates (weeks)',
                            display: true
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        stacked: true,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Number of defects',
                            display: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">

<body>
    
    <div>
        <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        
    </script>



</body>
```

Comment: When you say rotate, you mean 90 degrees clockwise? or something else?

Comment: Yes rotate 90 degrees clockwise

Comment: Have you checked this fiddle? There is no out of the box soln, but someone has made a fiddle with custom JS https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/L2vhwe6u/33/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom plugin, to make space you first need to increase the padding on the left, after that you can calculate the correct position by taking the average of the top and bottom y's of the chart area.

Also you should not include chart.js 2 times. When chart.js updates to V4 you will have V4 and V3 installed which will give unwanted behaviour.

Example:

```js
const customTitle = {
  id: 'customTitle',
  beforeLayout: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      display,
      font
    } = opts;
    if (!display) {
      return;
    }

    const {
      ctx
    } = chart;
    ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'

    const {
      width
    } = ctx.measureText(opts.text);
    chart.options.layout.padding.left = width * 1.1;
  },
  afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      font,
      text,
      color
    } = opts;
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        top,
        bottom,
        left,
        right
      }
    } = chart;

    if (opts.display) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color || Chart.defaults.color
      ctx.font = font || '12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
      ctx.fillText(text, 3, (top + bottom) / 2)
    }
  }
}

const labels = ['2021-06-07 00:00:00', '2021-06-08 00:00:00', '2021-06-09 00:00:00'];

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Fixed defects',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    data: ['2', '73', '34'],
    barThickness: 5
  }, {
    label: 'Open defects',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    data: ['0', '5', '2'],
    barThickness: 5

  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: '2021-06-07 00:00:00',
        max: '2021-09-10 00:00:00',
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'week'
        },
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      customTitle: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Number of defects',
        color: 'blue'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customTitle]
};

const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@^2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@^1"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas height="100px" id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I accepted this answer as it suited my needs better. And thank you for catching the two installed chart.js I would have missed that.